# ASP .NET web site first opening performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

Hi first i am sorry for my English but i have a problem that i cant find a solution.

I build a web site but when i open first it take 15-20 seconds to open image gallery in the default page than it get really fast like 1-2 second.

I read about IIS pools can be solution for this but I use some companies IIS and i cant modified IIS or something else can i do something on my project.

Can I tried anything on web config or something

I really thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at [autostart](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) Feature of 4.0 framework, i think it will help you